# Proof that the orthogonal projection onto a subspace satisfies the Cauchy Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to prove

$\left\|\hat{P}_{s}x\right\|^{2}_{2} \leqslant \left\| x \right\|_{2}\left\|\hat{P}_{s}x \right\|_{2} $ for all $x_1, x_2 \in X$

I am aware that I will need to use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality to prove this, however am not able to justify why $|<x, \hat{P}_{s}x>|_{2} =  \left\|\hat{P}_{s}x\right\|^{2}_{2}$ if I do use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 1):

By defintion of $\hat P_S$ being an orthogonal projection,
$$\langle \hat P_Sx, x-\hat P_S x\rangle = 0$$
This can be rewritten,  $$\langle \hat P_Sx,  x\rangle =\|\hat P_S x\|^2\tag{1}$$
Now, Cauchy-Schwarz means $$\langle \hat P_Sx,  x\rangle  \leq \|\hat  P_S x\|\|x\|\tag{2}$$
Injecting $(2)$ into $(1)$ yields the result.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, that's really helpful! It makes sense now

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is an orthogonal projection, then $P^\top P =P$, so
$$x^\top P^\top P x = x^\top P x.$$